# Easiest way to peel pomelos?

Tags: fruit, peeling

What is the easiest way to peel a pomelo and obtain skin-free wedges that are ready to eat?

Ever since I bought them a couple of years ago already peeled in Thailand, I have felt I am missing something.I will normally peel off the outer skin, then remove the wedges and remove their skin.

Does anyone know of a more clever way?

Comment: Try this! http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53997/is-there-a-quick-easy-mess-free-way-to-peel-an-orange-or-grapefruit/53998#53998 I can't say for sure that it works for pomelos, but it should!

Comment: I looked at the method, but don't really want to cut the wedges..the nice thing about pomelos is that they are dry, in the sense that you can remove the translucent skin without the mess you have with oranges, for instance

Comment: Sometimes there's no substitute for hard work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a summary of what I do:

1. Chop off the top part. About a little less than half an inch.
2. This will tell you how thick the skin is, and make it easier to peel.
3. Cut the a slice down the length of the fruit, and then repeat 3 more times, so your skin is then segmented into four quarters.
4. Peel as much of the skin off as possible.
5. Take your knife and peel/scrape off as much of the pith as you can. I ususaly take my paring knife, dig between the fruit and pith and then pull it off in large chunks. Once you're down to the translucent skin, you should be able to separate the segments easily. If you want, to just get in there and pull it apart, you can do so skipping this step.
6. With each individual segment, I put a slice near the centre from end to end, so I can pull the skin back in one large piece.

[Here's a video that summarizes it somewhat.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4K2P-fO2eM)

Comment: That is precisely what I am doing..I guess there is no shortcut then...